# Callback on asynchronous request , passed variables get overwritten when I dont want them to

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, coffeescript

I am currently looping through an array of location objects.  I am then calling out to google to get me a panorama for that location.  The problem is the request for this is asynchronous, so when the callback actually gets called, the location variable I passed is the last location in the array.

Here is example code, and console log output:

```
  for location in paginated_data.locations
    console.log location
    latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(location.latitude,location.longitude)
    @sv.getPanoramaByLocation(latLng, 50, (StreetViewPanoramaData, StreetViewStatus) =>
      console.log location          
    )
```

[image]

As you can see, in the initial loop the console sees the correct location, in the callback, it only shows the last one from the loop. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to fix this?

Comment: please post your callback, and the full function.

Comment: the callback is an anonymous function: (StreetViewPanoramaData, StreetViewStatus) => console.log location

Comment: getPanoramaByLocation is a google api function which is why i dont have control on what variables are passed to callback.  by default the google call returns StreetViewPanoramaData, StreetViewStatus, but I also need location

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE:

You should use the `do` keyword to have coffeescript create a separate closure for each loop iteration:

```
  for location in paginated_data.locations
    do (location) ->
      console.log location
      latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(location.latitude,location.longitude)
      @sv.getPanoramaByLocation(latLng, 50, (StreetViewPanoramaData, StreetViewStatus) =>
        console.log location
```

ORIGINAL (the not-so-coffeescript but still in coffeescript way of doing it):

You need to wrap your code in an [iife](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) so that it has its own scope and pass in `location`:

```
  for location in paginated_data.locations
    ((location) ->
      console.log location
      latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(location.latitude,location.longitude)
      @sv.getPanoramaByLocation(latLng, 50, (StreetViewPanoramaData, StreetViewStatus) =>
        console.log location          
      )(location)
```

or move the body of the `for` loop into a separate `function`

```
  getLocation = (location) ->
    console.log location
    latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(location.latitude,location.longitude)
    @sv.getPanoramaByLocation(latLng, 50, (StreetViewPanoramaData, StreetViewStatus) =>
       console.log location

  for location in paginated_data.locations
    getLocation(location)
```

Comment: The idiomatic way to do this in CoffeeScript is to use `do`: ["When using a JavaScript loop to generate functions, it's common to insert a closure wrapper in order to ensure that loop variables are closed over, and all the generated functions don't just share the final values. CoffeeScript provides the `do` keyword, which immediately invokes a passed function, forwarding any arguments."](http://coffeescript.org/#loops)

Comment: @muistooshort That is super handy! Updated. Thanks!

Comment: This common use case is exactly why CoffeeScript has `do`.